# Setting Windows screensaver require password with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I know that I can set screensaver values through the registry, but those apply at login.  I gather the correct way is to use the [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx) function, which then makes the changes apply immediately.

I am able to get and set the screensaver timeout values using the following:

```
$signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref int lpvParam, int flags );
"@

$systemParamInfo = Add-Type -memberDefinition  $signature -Name ScreenSaver -passThru

Function Get-ScreenSaverTimeout
{
  [Int32]$value = 0
  $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(14, 0, [REF]$value, 0)
  $($value/60)
}

Function Set-ScreenSaverTimeout
{
  Param ([Int32]$value)
  $seconds = $value * 60
  [Int32]$nullVar = 0
  $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(15, $seconds, [REF]$nullVar, 2)
}
```

from https://powershellreflections.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/control-your-screensaver-with-powershell/

I am trying to change the flag for "On resume, display logon screen".  Getting the value with the following is successful:

```
function Get-ScreenSaverSecure 
{
  [Int32]$value = 0
  $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(118, 0, [REF]$value, 0)
  $value
}
```

However, setting the value with:

```
Function Set-ScreenSaverSecure
{
  [Int32]$nullVar = 0
  $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(119, $true, [REF]$nullVar, 2)
}
```

does not set the flag.  From the MSDN link, I think I should be passing SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE (which is uiParam 119) a $true or $false, depending on the mode, however neither seem to apply.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ["If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms724947). `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`; `if (-not $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(...)) { throw [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new() }`. On my machine, I get `This program is blocked by group policy.` regardless of whether I try to turn the setting on or off, but the basic approach should be OK.

Comment: Why are you reading with `118` and setting the value with `119`?

Answer (score 2):

I used function by @Tim AtLee and tailored as follows:

```
Function Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon
{
    Param ([Int32]$value)
    [Int32]$nullVar = 0
    $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(119, $value, [REF]$nullVar, 2)
}
```

then called by:

```
Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon(0)
```

to set the 'On resume, display logon' flag as unchecked; or

```
Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon(1)
```

to set the 'On resume, display logon' flag as checked

Comment: Do you have a link to the original function?