# How to disable Password protect the screen saver in group policy with a powershell command/script?

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I want to disable Password protection the screen saver in group policy with a PowerShell command/script.

I have run this command it didn't work. still shows as enabled in the group policy

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name ScreenSaveUsePassword -Value 0
```

i have tried below but it didn't work.

[Setting Windows screensaver require password with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578414/setting-windows-screensaver-require-password-with-powershell)

following the function on above StackOverflow link when i run,

```sql
Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon(0)
```

it outputs an error.

```yaml
you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this PowerShell command/script that you can use to disable password protection for the screen saver in group policy

**New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Control Panel\Display -Name ScreenSaverIsSecure -Value 0 -Force**

This command will create a new registry key called ScreenSaverIsSecure under the HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Control Panel\Display key. The value of the registry key will be set to 0, which will disable password protection for the screen saver.

To apply this change to all users, you can use the following command:

**New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\User -Name ScreenSaverIsSecure -Value 0 -Force**

This will create the same registry key under the HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\User key, which will apply the change to all users.

You can also use the following command to apply the change to a specific OU:

**$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "OU=YourOU,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"
New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies$ou -Name ScreenSaverIsSecure -Value 0 -Force**

This will create the registry key under the HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies<OU> key, where  is the name of the OU you want to apply the change to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. those commands were executed but still, I can see Password protect the screensaver is enabled in the local group policy. (User config>Administrative templates>Personalization>Password protect the screensaver)

Comment: @DMUN you are editing a setting outside of the "template" system so it's normal that you don't see it in the GUI editor. My advise is to read up on how local policies work: settings you make in the GUI get stored in a .pol file (you have seperate files for user and machine config). This is what you see in the GUI tool, not the state of this setting in the registry.